# PYTHON Basic Text Browser/Scraper. How to remove blank lines but keep at least one between paragraphs

Tags: python

I have created a basic text browser/scraper that works for what I want it to do.
However, when the text from a site is received there are a hell of alot of extra blank lines.
Is there a way to remove the extra blank lines but keep at least one blank line between paragraphs?

Here is my code....

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = input('Enter a URL starting with https or http: ')
host = url
webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(host)
print('result code: ' + str(webUrl.getcode()))
data = webUrl.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features="html.parser")
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
text = soup.get_text()
print (text)
input('Scroll Up or Press ENTER to Exit')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "between paragraphs"? Between `<p>` tags or generally reduce consecutive blank lines to one blank line everywhere?

Comment: Yes, generally reduce consecutive blank lines to one blank line everywhere. I think it will make the output more user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.sub` to replace multiple newlines, with optional whitespaces between and before them, with a single newline:

```
import re
text = re.sub(r"\s*\n", "\n", text)
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!